# How should I compare a datetime stamp to a timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

I'm struggling to find a straight forward solution -- For a given datetimestamp how do I find out if it is before or after simply a time, not a time and date? I'm assuming it is the same timezone.

For example if I'm checking if a time is after 4pm (16:00) do I need to extract the date and the timezone from the date, to do the comparison or is there a simpler method?

```
var d = new Date(2019, 4, 9, 16, 30, 6);
console.log(d.toString());
//Thu May 09 2019 16:30:06 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

isItBeforeFourPM(d);
```

In the past I've been able to use < or > for comparison for a date, but that comparison assumes I have two datetime objects in the same format.

```
ex.
var d2 = new Date(2019, 4, 8, 16, 30, 6); // 4:30pm
var d3 = new Date(2019, 4, 8, 16, 00, 6); // 4:00pm
if(d2 > d3){
   console.log('it is after 4pm');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't using d.getHours() and d.getMinutes() give you what you need from the original ?

Comment: @charlietfl it does, and I could use it, but I was searching for a way to compare a known full timestamp against simply a time without knowing the date or the timezone.  -- I'll use the .getHours() and .getMinutes() until a better solution presents itself.

Comment: You should always compare against the UTC times.